# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type Bloc<dynamic,dynamic>

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

> Error:  I/flutter ( 5919): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   ( 5919): The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
>   I/flutter ( 5919):         BlocProvider.of() called with a context
>   that does not contain a Bloc of type Bloc. I/flutter ( 5919):         No ancestor could be found
>   starting from the context that was passed to I/flutter ( 5919):
>   BlocProvider.of>(). I/flutter ( 5919):
>   This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the
>   BlocProvider. I/flutter ( 5919):         The context used was:
>   BlocBuilder, dynamic>(dirty, state: I/flutter (
>   5919): _BlocBuilderBaseState,
>   dynamic>#55a7d(lifecycle state: created)) I/flutter ( 5919): The
>   relevant error-causing widget was: I/flutter ( 5919):   MaterialApp
>   /lib/main.dart:35:12

Here's my main

```
void main() {
  final StorageRepository storageRepository = StorageRepository();
  final AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository =
      AuthenticationRepository();
  runApp(BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      create: (_) => AuthenticationBloc(
          authenticationRepository: authenticationRepository,
          storageRepository: storageRepository),
      child: MyApp()));
}
```

MaterialApp Widget

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple),
      home: BlocBuilder(
        builder: (context, state) {
          print(state);
          if (state is Authenticated) {
            return MainPage();
          } else if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage();
          } else if (state is Uninitialized) {
            return SplashScreen();
          }

          return Container();
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to give the Bloc and State type to the BlocBuilder Widget

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple),
      /// You need to specify the type here, 
      /// that's why you got error Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          print(state);
          if (state is Authenticated) {
            return MainPage();
          } else if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage();
          } else if (state is Uninitialized) {
            return SplashScreen();
          }

          return Container();
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error, itself suggest `BlocProvider` not accessing the right `context` to use the bloc

`MultiBlocProvider` provides the ability to add multiple providers which then can get the right context access as `MultiBlocProvider` converts the `BlocProvider` list into a tree of nested
`BlocProvider` widgets.

```
MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<YourBloc>(
                create: (BuildContext context) =>)
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: BlocBuilder<YourBloc, YourState>(
```